# non zero initial value in second order differential

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

solve $y''+12y'-12y=0,y(\pi)=-2,y'(\pi)=-20$

I have only done $y(0)$ problems so far, how do I deal with these type of initial value?

answer: $y=-4e^{3(t-\pi)}+2e^{-4(t-\pi)}$

Comment: What's the problem? You've got $y(x) = C_{1}e^{..} + C_{2}e^{..}$, now you could make system of linear equations: $y(\pi) = -2$ and $y'(\pi) = -20$

Comment: do I just substitute $\pi$ to $x$ in $C1*e^x+C2*e^x$? but the answer seems to be subtracting $x - \pi$ which I do not understand

Comment: You just need to put your value(points) into your equation, to find the constants.

Comment: but what I don't understand is the $t-\pi$ part

Comment: $e^{3(t-\pi)}=e^{-3\pi}e^{3t}$

Answer (score 0):

First of all represent our equation:
$\lambda^{2}+12\lambda-12 = 0$, which have two solutions:
$\lambda_{1} = -6+4\sqrt{3}$ and $\lambda_{2} = -6 - 4\sqrt{3}$, so we got:
$$C_{1}e^{(-6-4\sqrt{3})x} + C_{2}e^{(-6+4\sqrt{3})x} = y(x)$$, so
$$C_{1}e^{(-6-4\sqrt{3})\pi} +C_{2}e^{(-6+4\sqrt{3})\pi} = -2$$
$$C_{1}(-6-4\sqrt{3})e^{(-6-4\sqrt{3})\pi} + C_{2}(-6+4\sqrt{3})e^{(-6+4\sqrt{3})\pi} = -20$$, now you could determine the constants, and find the answer.